# Python pattern matching issue

Tags: python, regex

I have following two strings

```
root = 'svn\\456'
dir = 'svn\\456\\765'

pattern = re.compile('^'+root)
matched = pattern.match(dir)
```

I always get matched None. But if I do like following

```
root = 'svn\\456'
dir = 'svn\456\\765'

pattern = re.compile('^'+root)
matched = pattern.match(dir)
```

I get matched as True.

sorry if its a really basic thing which I am missing here. But I am just starting with python.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `pattern = re.compile('^'+re.escape(root))` and raw strings.

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked!!!

Comment: Posted, please check.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using `'svn\\456'` as a pattern is that `\` is a special character that requires escaping, so if you'll change the first pattern to: `'svn\\\\456'` you'll get a match:

```
import re
root = 'svn\\\\456'
dir = 'svn\\456\\765'

pattern = re.compile('^'+root)
matched = pattern.match(dir) # matched!
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a literal string that you are trying to use to create a regex object. It contains a special regex character that must be escaped.

You need to use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) function for that.

Here is an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/4qNWvm):

```
import re
root = r'svn\456'
dir = r'svn\456\765'

pattern = re.compile('^'+re.escape(root))
matched = pattern.match(dir)
print(matched)
```